# flutter devtools in vs code is not activating with the error "Activating Dart DevTools failed."

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I have run flutter upgrade and flutter pub pub global activate devtools
there's no problem and all good output.
and here's the end of my devtool results

```html
Precompiling executables...
Precompiled devtools:devtools.
Installed executable devtools.
Activated devtools 0.9.3+3.
```

but when I try to run dart: open devtools it shows me this alert box
[image]

and when I click on Activate Dart Devtools, it just show me an error with not much good info.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should run the command as-is in the error message (without any `flutter` prefix) to match what the VS Code extension is doing and (hopefully) get the same error.

If that doesn't help, try running the **Dart: Capture Logs** before trying to activate through VS Code, which should log the output from the commands.

If all else fails, please file an issue at https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code both to figure out what's wrong and to improve the handling of this to make it easier to track down in future. Thanks!

Comment: could it be the issue that my computer cannot run pub, it has to be flutter pub, and i find no good ways to get pub working, everyone online just says: please use flutter pub instead

Comment: @ZhangBruce In this instance, you should run the command as printed in the message without any "flutter" prefix. This is how VS Code runs DevTools always, regardless of whether your project is Flutter or not (this is to avoid potentially having two different versions of DevTools for flutter/non-flutter projects, as they have their own pub caches).

Comment: @ZhangBruce you do usually need to use "flutter pub" for things like fetching packages, but this is a special case - you're not interacting with your Flutter app, but rather just running a Dart package (DevTools). I appreciate it's a little confusing, but that's how it is right now. If you cannot run "pub" on its own, you may need to provide the full path (which is `(Flutter SDK)/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/pub`). Please file an issue at the address above if you get stuck, and we can track this down there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just happened to face the same issue again (Dec-2021-flutter 2.5.2,Mac, VSCode).
What i did was

1. sudo nano /etc/paths
2. Add this line Home$/.pub-cache/bin
   ($Home = your flutter directory)
3. Save it..
4. Run this command*  - pub global activate devtools (or pub global deactivate devtools) play around to get the desired result.
   (*if this command not running properly, it means your path to it is wrong)
   Good luck